# Buttons in page are not doing anything

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to programming and I have a project to fix this page. www.recargamex.com

the problem is, that the buttons are not doing anything at all; I looked in the index.html file for any errors but the debbugger is not showing up anything being an error. I don´t know where or what can be causing this buttons not to work (I see that the url changes to load the  thing with a hashtag (recargamex.com/topup#) but they still don't do a thing.

If you could help me with this I really like programming and I wish to learn more, but I don't want to be discouraged by this, I really don't know what to do!

The index.html code is here

http://pastebin.com/3Jnkjzee

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please paste your code with the question so other can have a look at it and help you out

Comment: I couldn't the code was too long and it would only let me paste less than 30000 characters.

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle.com and provide referance of link

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/v3kzLx8n/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#buttonid").click(function() {
     //Code in here//
 }); 
 });
 </script>
```

This should work. You defined script in body, after the code. Put it in head section.

Comment: Ok, so what you are telling me is to put that on the HEAD?

I need one of those for each button? or that only script tag should do everything for all buttons?

Comment: Well, everytime you're done with scripting, close the script and if you want to create another script somewhere else in the page, open and close the script tag again. But avoid writing script if you haven't defined whatever you're using there. And it should work for all the buttons if you wrote your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point start you might want be using debugger tools for client side debugging. Use firebug plugin for firefox. Inspect the element and in your case the button

Comment: When I inspect the button this shows up:

<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#detalles1" role="button">Ver detalles &raquo;</a></p>

Is it a bad way to manage/use buttons?

Is the answer on the top a better way to do so?